# Django model join in view queryset for template table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I need some help with trying to join 2 models (but really 3) into a queryset so I can display values from both models inside a template table.

I'll use a simple donor and charity model as an example

```
class Donor(models.Model):
       donor_name = models.CharField(50) #assuming only one donor in the system

class Charity(models.Model):
       charity_name = models.CharField(50) 

class AmountGiven(models.Model):
      donor = models.ForeignKey(Donor)
      charity = models.ForeignKey(Charity) 
      donation_date = models.DateField()
      amount = models.IntegerField()
```

I'm looking for the correct queryset which I can loop into a table which shows the total amount donated by the person like this query would return

```
SELECT B.charity_name, sum(C.amount) as total
FROM customer A, product B, amount_given C
WHERE A.donor_name = C.donor
AND B.charity_name = C.charity
GROUP BY B.charity_name
ORDER BY b.charity_name
```

At the end of the day, I would love to put the results into a list which I can then loop into a table like this

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
{% for result in results %}
  <tr>
     <td>{{ result.charity_name }}</td>
     <td>{{ result.total }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

result = AmountGiven.objects.values('charity__charity_name').annotate(total=Sum('amount'))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#topics-db-aggregation

Then in your template it should be like this:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
{% for result in results %}
  <tr>
     <td>{{ result['charity__charity_name'] }}</td>
     <td>{{ result['total'] }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am giving my solution based on a better design approach in my opinion

You have Donor and Charity, and from my understanding Donor can donate to many charities and charity may be donated by many donors. In this case we have a `ManytoMany` relationship. However, it needs extra information about each relationship. This is called in Django `Extra fields on many-to-many relationships` Where you create model that contain the relationship extra information. So let me show you how this can be done in your case.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Sum

class Donor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Charity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    donations = models.ManyToManyField(Donor, through='Donation')

    def donations_sum(self):
        return self.donation_set.aggregate(s=Sum("amount"))["s"]

class Donation(models.Model):
    donor = models.ForeignKey(Donor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    charity = models.ForeignKey(Charity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    donation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Now the `Donation` model will contain these extra information about the relationship between `Donor` and `Charity`

Now you can do the following

```
## Create donors
>>> mike = Donor.objects.create(name="Mike Smith")
>>> john = Donor.objects.create(name="John Smith")

# Create charites
>>> charity1 = Charity.objects.create(name="Clean Beach")
>>> charity2 = Charity.objects.create(name="Help Old People")

# create donations
>>> donation1 = Donation(donor=mike, charity=charity1, amount=2000)
>>> donation2 = Donation(donor=mike, charity=charity2, amount=500)
>>> donation3 = Donation(donor=john, charity=charity1, amount=1500)

# now in order to get each charity total donations
>>> charity1.donations_sum() ## 3500
```

So in your template you can use it easily. You can read more about this topic in here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships